# javascript access php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible a html/javascript page can retrieve the value of a variable from other php page?

For example `test.php` and `main.html` are 2 pages. 
`test.php` just echo the value of one variable V.
do you know if `main.html` could retrieve the value V from `test.php`.

one idea could be something like a tag with attribute `src=test.php`?

Comment: Do you want a simple "yes" or "no" ? How about google <- it answers everything

Comment: You have many ways, Localstorage or Querystring.

Comment: Databases, sessions, localstorage, AJAX...

Comment: You can start a session and store the variable into a session variable. That would be the easiest way.

Comment: how is main.html generated ? Static html file ?

Comment: JSON was invented for this. Look it up.

Comment: Do you really need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**. You could make an ajax post or get request to that php page and get values. You could use jquery to make the process easier. i.e.:

main.html

```
<script src="pathtojs/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var V;
$.get("test.php",function(data){
    V = data.V;
},"json")
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php
$data = array("V" => "your variable value");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you navigating form one pahe to the other?
If so, a cookie or localstorage could do the trick.
A query string parameter could also work.

Comment: I think this should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly, but there is a workaround in the form of AJAX. I personally prefer using jQuery.
You can use the jQuery `$.get();` method to retrieve the variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var phpVar;
   $.get("test.php", function(data){
      phpVar = data;
   });
});
```

with the test.php file, you need to `echo $var;`
otherwise the `data` parameter of the `$.get();` function will be blank. It contains everything that is generated on test.php so if you only generate your variable, it will only contain your variable

Answer (score -1):

ok ajax is one method (for me not preferable,but also main.html is only html,not php echoing), but what about iframes?

for example if main.html had `<iframe src=http://serverDomain/test.php></iframe>` and test.php echo some javascript which using DOM can innerHTML the value of variable in the main page.